# How do I ask for not just number of rows and columns for dynamic 2D array but also display in tabular format?

Tags: c++

> Write a program that asks the user for a number of rows and columns,
>   create a dynamic 2D int array based on those numbers, allow the user
>   to fill the array, then display the contents in tabular format. (Do
>   not forget to deallocate memory.)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ROWS;
    int COLS;

    int *numbers;

    cout << "Please enter the number of rows: " << endl;
    cin >> ROWS;
    cout << "Now enter the number of columns: " << endl;
    cin >> COLS;

    numbers = new integers[][];

    << "Please enter a number, press -1 to stop: ";
    do
    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
    >> integers[i][j]
    while (integers != -1)

    delete[][] integers;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the contents in a tabular form, you should set the width of the output stream before during insertion. For example:

```c++
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < COLUMNS; ++k)
    { std::cout << integers[i][k]; std::cout.width(5); }
    //                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

It should print something like this (for a 3x8 array):

```c++
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```